# Big-O notation, equality

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, solution-verification

I have the following definition of the **Big-O notation**:

$$
\begin{align*}
&f(x)=O(g(x))\text{ as }x\to a\\
&\qquad\text{iff}\quad
\exists m>0,
\;\exists \delta>0
\Big(0<|{x-a}|<\delta\;\to\;|{f(x)}|\le m\,g(x)\Big).
\end{align*}
$$

But given the previous definition the following property/expression, that I would like to prove, is not defined yet:
$$
f\cdot O(g)=O(fg).\tag{*}
$$

> What does (*) means? (Technically, practically i think that it is clear to me)
> The definition does suppose that the $O$ is only on one side.

**My proof** (I hope it is correct. One has first to prove the equivalence of the definition with the $\limsup$ equivalent)

Let be $h$ a map such that $h=O(g)$, then
\begin{gather*}
\limsup_{x\to \infty}\left|\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}\right|<\infty
\end{gather*}
thus
\begin{gather*}
\limsup_{x\to \infty}\left|\frac{f(x)h(x)}{f(x)g(x)}\right|<\infty,
\end{gather*}
which proves that $fh=O(fg)$ and since $h$ was an arbitrary map $O(g)$ we have $fO(g)=O(fg)$.

Comment: It means that if you multiply $f$ by a function which is $O(g)$ then you get a function which is $O(fg)$. I must say I really dislike this notation, and really don't like to read articles which use it all the time. I like when everything is more formal. But that's how it is, this notation exists.

Comment: @Mark, thank you! Then it's an enhancement of the notation; I'll add a second definition for that. I don't like it too, but I need to understand it.

Comment: I have a little confusion. Do you need the proof of $\ast$ or do you want to read the statement in $\ast$ ?

Comment: @HKLee, thank you for writing. The Q is for me closed. I needed to understand the meaning. After understanding it, I proved it. I add my prove in my question.